# Stopping Eclipse from opening tabs in other perspectives

Tags: java, eclipse

I recently created a new perspective, "Java History", which I have dedicated exclusively to browsing local history, reverting changes, etc.

My problem is that whenever I select a history revision for a given file (i.e. History tab -> double click a revision), Eclipse opens a tab for this revision BOTH in my main Java development perspective AND my Java History perspective, which pollutes my development perspective.

How can I get around this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is normal behavior that cannot be changed: the revision is opened in the **editor area** and its contents are always independent of the perspective.

Comment: Puno ti hvala, majstore! This is curious though..is there no way to associate separate editor instances with separate perspectives?

Comment: No, the editor area is a singleton and in fact it is the anchor against which the location of all other views is specified.